# Android 13 WebView Cache

Tags: android, webview

0

Need help with webview cache in Android 13.

"The Android system webview custom cache file has been deprecated and removed in Android 13. New apps and any app updates will now use the operating system default cache location. This means users who update your app will have their existing cache invalidated during the update process. As a result users may need to re-login or set options within the app should that data be stored in the cache."

Everything works in Android 12 and below, if you close the app and reopen you will be logged in.

Any solution for Android 13 ?